# What is the proper way to resume an Android Phonegap app?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm not sure if this is expected, if it's a bug and whether or not there's a workaround.

When a user hits the home button in our Android Phonegap app, the application minimizes properly.
When the user clicks the icon to launch the app, it restarts from the beginning. This is undesirable.

After a user minimizes the app by clicking the home button, there are two ways the app will resume properly:

1. A long press on the home button and clicking the app will resume the app in its last state.
2. Clicking a notification in the status bar (push notification) will resume the app in its last state.

So  my question is, what do we need to do to resume the app in the same way those above two items do when the user clicks on the app icon from the desktop? The app is running and healthy as item 1 listed above confirms.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I actually can't reproduce this issue. Can you provide more details?

Comment: I was afraid of that. I assume something is wrong in our build since I don't see other similar questions. The problem really boils down to the fact that every time a user clicks on the app icon from the app tray or a home screen, the app restarts from square one. Splash screen and everything. Is that the expected behavior? If you long press on the home button and select the app from the list of running apps, the app pops back up in the state it was minimized in. That's what we want always. We're not sure what could be wrong.

Comment: Ryan, you should email me directly "simon [dot] macdonald [at] gmail [dot] com". I'll probably need to look at your manifest.xml and possibly the main class that extends DroidGap. It seems like a very specific problem.

Comment: Thanks, Simon. Your help is much appreciated. I'll shoot you an e-mail with more specific information.

Comment: Ryan, was this ever resolved? I am having the exact same issue. I have found several other questions asking about it but none of them seem to have answers.

Comment: Yes we did eventually get it figured out, but I don't have the code with me at the moment. The selected answer should help you - it looks very familiar to the solution that helped us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem . My app was getting restarted when i click the app icon to relaunch the already running app in the background.

Basically if the `android:launchMode` is set to standard or not set ,then a new intent is created for the app and the old paused state of app is not resumed .

So the best way around i found was to apply

> android:launchMode="singleTask"

in the AndroidManifest.xml -> inside  `<activity>` .

please conside this example :

```
 <activity android:name="Example" android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
               android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
                 android:launchMode="singleTask">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>
```